# Merge 2 columns in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a data set with columns I'd like to merge similar to this:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), Product = c('Y', NA, NA, 'Z', NA), Type = c(NA, 'D', 'G', NA, NA)))

DF
ID   Product Type
1       Y     NA
2       NA    D
3       NA    G
4       Z     NA
5       NA    NA
```

which I would like to look like this:

```
DF
ID   Product Type  Category
1       Y     NA      Y
2       NA    D       D
3       NA    G       G
4       Z     NA      Z
5       NA    NA      NA
```

My Code is:

```
  DF[,Category := na.omit(c(Product,Type)), by = ID][,c("Product","Type"):=NULL]
```

The problem that I have is that I would like to have for the `Category` to be `NA` when both `Product` and `Type` are `NA`s. Also, I don't know if my code works because my data set has over 200,000 rows.

Comment: `dplyr::coalesce` is for this purpose: `library(dplyr) ; DF %>% mutate(Category = coalesce(Product, Type))` or with data.table grammar, `DF[, Category := coalesce(Product, Type)]`

Answer (score 5):

```
DF[ , Category := ifelse(is.na(Product), Type, Product)]

#   ID Product Type Category
#1:  1       Y   NA        Y
#2:  2      NA    D        D
#3:  3      NA    G        G
#4:  4       Z   NA        Z
#5:  5      NA   NA       NA
```

This is assuming if there are values for both `Product` and `Type`, you want `Product` in `Category`

Answer (score 4):

We can do this in two assignments and avoid `ifelse` as assignment in place (`:=`) is faster and efficient.

```
DF[, Category := Product][is.na(Product), Category := Type][]
#      ID Product Type Category
#1:  1       Y   NA        Y
#2:  2      NA    D        D
#3:  3      NA    G        G
#4:  4       Z   NA        Z
#5:  5      NA   NA       NA
```

---

Or if we assume that there will be only a maximum 1 non-NA value per row for Product/Type, then `pmax` can be used.

```
DF[, Category := pmax(Product, Type, na.rm = TRUE)][]
#    ID Product Type Category
#1:  1       Y   NA        Y
#2:  2      NA    D        D
#3:  3      NA    G        G
#4:  4       Z   NA        Z
#5:  5      NA   NA       NA
```

#### Benchmarks

```
DF1 <- DF[rep(1:nrow(DF), 1e6)]
DF2 <- copy(DF1)
DF3 <- copy(DF1)
system.time(DF1[, Category := Product][is.na(Product), Category := Type])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.16    0.06    0.17 
system.time(DF2[ , Category := ifelse(is.na(Product), Type, Product)])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  1.35    0.19    1.53 

system.time(DF3[ ,Category := pmax(Product, Type, na.rm = TRUE)])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.04    0.02    0.06
```

EDIT: Updated with the benchmarks and it clearly shows both the methods mentioned in my post are efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the timings, I didn't think that the `ifelse` version would be that much slower.